# Load environment specific variables in puppet template

Tags: ruby, puppet

I'm trying to configure a properties file in a puppet module. The properties file should end up with content like this:

```
server_url=https://my-login.com/server
token_url=https://my-login.com/token
client_id=my-application
```

We have multiple environments that the application will be deployed to (development, staging and production), the `server_url` and `token_url` will be different in each environment, but the `client_id` will always be the same. So I made an erb template like this:

```
server_url=<%=@server_url%>
token_url=<%=@token_url%>
client_id=my-application
```

And a manifest file like this:

```
# $env will be DEV, STG or PRD
$server_url = 'https://my-login-dev.com/server'
$token_url = 'https://my-login-dev.com/token'
​
file {'/apps/my-application/common/client.properties':
  ensure  => 'present',
  content => template("common/client.properties.erb"),
}
```

I want the values of the `server_url` and `token_url` to be set based on the value of the `env` variable. Ideally this would work by choosing a particular file to include. For example, have an `urls.properties` file for each environment, which the variables get loaded from. So `urls.properties.dev` would contain something like:

```
server_url=https://my-login.com/server
token_url=https://my-login.com/token
```

And then you could just include it like so:

```
# server_url and token_url set up by the following line
include urls.properties.${env}

file {'/apps/my-application/common/client.properties':
  ensure  => 'present',
  content => template("common/client.properties.erb"),
}
```

I can't find any documentation on how to do this, and I can't find a way to make it work by hacking around.

Is it possible to achieve this? Is there another approach I should be taking to solve the problem? (I don't want to use partial templates, as I don't want the file to be split into lots of chunks).

Comment: You are making this way harder on yourself than you need to. You could solve this quite simply with a custom fact for your environment. What is the convention you are using to categorize the servers by their environment?

Comment: Have you already checked [hiera](https://docs.puppet.com/hiera/3.2/)?